# SQL rank counting occurences

Tags: sql, rank, dense-rank

In my table I have data from employee contracts like this:
[image]

And I want to get job position in time periods, something like this

| login | ValidFrom | ValidTo | JobPosition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bcde | 2019-07-01 | 2019-09-30 | Project Manager |
| bcde | 2020-01-09 | 2020-06-16 | Head of Center of Excellence |
| bcde | 2020-06-17 | 2021-07-31 | Team Leader |
| bcde | 2021-08-01 | 2099-12-31 | Head of Center of Excellence |

So I write query:

```
select DimEmployeeId, JobPosition, login, min(ValidFrom), max(ValidTo)
from employeeContracts
group by DimEmployeeId, JobPosition, login
```

But It doesn't work in this case (if someone has the same JobPosition), so I decided to use dense_rank, like this:

```
select login, ValidFrom, ValidTo, JobPosition
,dense_rank() OVER (Partition BY JobPosition ORDER BY login, ValidFrom, ValidTo, JobPosition) as no
from employeeContracts
```

and after that

```
select DimEmployeeId, JobPosition, login, min(ValidFrom), max(ValidTo)
from employeeContracts
group by DimEmployeeId, JobPosition, no, login
```

but problem is dense_rank doesn't work as I need ;) I want to get something like this:

| login | ValidFrom | ValidTo | JobPosition | no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bcde | 2019-07-01 | 2019-09-30 | Project Manager | 1 |
| bcde | 2020-01-09 | 2020-06-16 | Head of Center of Excellence | 2 |
| bcde | 2020-06-17 | 2020-07-31 | Team Leader | 3 |
| bcde | 2020-08-01 | 2021-03-31 | Team Leader | 3 |
| bcde | 2021-04-01 | 2021-06-30 | Team Leader | 3 |
| bcde | 2021-07-01 | 2021-07-31 | Team Leader | 3 |
| bcde | 2021-08-01 | 2021-12-31 | Head of Center of Excellence | 4 |
| bcde | 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-09 | Head of Center of Excellence | 4 |
| bcde | 2022-02-01 | 2022-05-09 | Head of Center of Excellence | 4 |
| bcde | 2022-05-09 | 2099-12-31 | Head of Center of Excellence | 4 |

and after that use query to get final result:

```
select DimEmployeeId, JobPosition, login, min(ValidFrom), max(ValidTo)
from employeeContracts
group by DimEmployeeId, JobPosition, no, login
```

#### Example Data Scheme

```sql
CREATE TABLE employeeContracts (
  login text,
  ValidFrom datetime,
  ValidTo datetime,
  JobPosition text
);

INSERT INTO employeeContracts (login, ValidFrom, ValidTo, JobPosition) 
VALUES ('bcde', '2019-07-01', '2019-09-30', 'Project Manager');

INSERT INTO employeeContracts (login, ValidFrom, ValidTo, JobPosition) 
VALUES ('bcde', '2020-01-09', '2020-06-16', 'Head of Center of Excellence');

INSERT INTO employeeContracts (login, ValidFrom, ValidTo, JobPosition) 
VALUES ('bcde', '2020-06-17', '2020-07-31', 'Team Leader');

INSERT INTO employeeContracts (login, ValidFrom, ValidTo, JobPosition) 
VALUES ('bcde', '2020-08-01', '2021-03-31', '   Team Leader');

INSERT INTO employeeContracts (login, ValidFrom, ValidTo, JobPosition) 
VALUES ('bcde', '2021-04-01', '2021-06-30', '   Team Leader');

INSERT INTO employeeContracts (login, ValidFrom, ValidTo, JobPosition) 
VALUES ('bcde', '2021-07-01', '2021-07-31', '   Team Leader');

INSERT INTO employeeContracts (login, ValidFrom, ValidTo, JobPosition) 
VALUES ('bcde', '2021-08-01', '2021-12-31', '   Head of Center of Excellence');

INSERT INTO employeeContracts (login, ValidFrom, ValidTo, JobPosition) 
VALUES ('bcde', '2022-01-01', ' 2022-05-09', 'Head of Center of Excellence');

INSERT INTO employeeContracts (login, ValidFrom, ValidTo, JobPosition) 
VALUES ('bcde', '2022-02-01', '2022-05-09', 'Head of Center of Excellence');

INSERT INTO employeeContracts (login, ValidFrom, ValidTo, JobPosition) 
VALUES ('bcde', '2022-05-09', '2099-12-31', 'Head of Center of Excellence');
```

This can be tested [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a92ec/7)

Comment: I use Sql dedicated pool in Azure Synapse

Comment: Thanks but the fiddle is missing values for DimEmployeeId. Need that value to understand what results you're *currently* getting.

Comment: Sorry my mistake ;) We can skip DimEmployeeId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a "Gaps and Islands" problem.  One way of approaching it is to identify and assign rankings to each "island" (or date ranges for each JobPosition).

| login | ValidFrom | ValidTo | JobPosition | PrevPosition | JobPositionGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bcde | 2019-07-01 00:00:00 | 2019-09-30 00:00:00 | Project Manager | *null* | 1 |
| bcde | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 | 2020-06-16 00:00:00 | Head of Center of Excellence | Project Manager | 2 |
| bcde | 2020-06-17 00:00:00 | 2020-07-31 00:00:00 | Team Leader | Head of Center of Excellence | 3 |
| bcde | 2020-08-01 00:00:00 | 2021-03-31 00:00:00 | Team Leader | Team Leader | 3 |
| bcde | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 2021-06-30 00:00:00 | Team Leader | Team Leader | 3 |
| bcde | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 2021-07-31 00:00:00 | Team Leader | Team Leader | 3 |
| bcde | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | Head of Center of Excellence | Team Leader | 4 |
| bcde | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-05-09 00:00:00 | Head of Center of Excellence | Head of Center of Excellence | 4 |
| bcde | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 2022-05-09 00:00:00 | Head of Center of Excellence | Head of Center of Excellence | 4 |
| bcde | 2022-05-09 00:00:00 | 2099-12-31 00:00:00 | Head of Center of Excellence | Head of Center of Excellence | 4 |

Then apply your min/max logic, grouping by the ranking number:

```
 SELECT grp.JobPositionGroup
        , grp.JobPosition
        , grp.Login
        , MIN(grp.ValidFrom) AS ValidFrom
        , MAX(grp.ValidTo) AS ValidTo
 FROM (
         SELECT  cron.*
                 , SUM( IF( JobPosition = PrevPosition, 0, 1) ) OVER(
                            ORDER BY ValidFrom, ValidTo
                 )  AS JobPositionGroup
         FROM   (
                    SELECT ec.*
                          , LAG(JobPosition, 1) OVER (
                               ORDER BY ValidFrom, ValidTo
                          ) AS PrevPosition
                    FROM   employeeContracts ec
                 )
                 cron
         ) grp
 GROUP BY grp.JobPositionGroup
          , grp.JobPosition
          , grp.Login
```

*Results:*

| JobPositionGroup | JobPosition | Login | ValidFrom | ValidTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Project Manager | bcde | 2019-07-01 00:00:00 | 2019-09-30 00:00:00 |
| 2 | Head of Center of Excellence | bcde | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 | 2020-06-16 00:00:00 |
| 3 | Team Leader | bcde | 2020-06-17 00:00:00 | 2021-07-31 00:00:00 |
| 4 | Head of Center of Excellence | bcde | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | 2099-12-31 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bddec08b50937ba00d3b3a701de03af7)*

Comment: thank you, it works! ;) but I had to change IF construction to CASE WHEN

Comment: Gotcha.  I went with MySQL syntax based on the fiddle, but CASE is probably better as it's more standard and works in a wider variety of db's.